# Error Code:1262 when loading to mySQL

Tags: mysql, bigdata, csv

I have a little bit of an issue when trying to load tsv file 2gb to mysql database. Error Code:1262

As this is quite big file how can i open/change so i can load it into the system?

Comment: Definition of Error 1262: SQLSTATE: 01000 (ER_WARN_TOO_MANY_RECORDS) Row %ld was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns.

Answer (score -1):

this will be csv file and as you aware that it is to big.
if you are in local server you can change in .ini file and increase the limit for uploading file and if you are using web server add in .htaccess file

in the .htcaccess file add the following:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 500M
php_value post_max_size 500M
```

in php.ini add:

```
upload_max_filesize = 500M
post_max_size = 500M
```

or you can split your csv file

Comment: if i would decide to split it how would load file query would change to reflect bulk upload?